# What drives Ferengi to work so hard for money given that the technology required in a post-scarcity society is available?

Tags: star-trek, money, ferengi

Given the availability of replicators, why are Ferengis so hard up for money? What drives them to continue to work so hard for money when they don't have to?

When it comes to humans, many would retire once they have enough money. Financial freedom and early retirement is a dream for almost all humans I know today.

Comment: Well, for one thing, it’s cultural. We work hard for reputation on this site, for example, even though we can’t spend it on anything. For another, post-scarcity is less a characteristic of society of than of *goods*.  Breathable air is post-scarcity on Earth, in most places. Similarly, on *Star Trek* food may be post-scarcity…but *Enterprises* aren’t, or photon torpedoes, or latinum, or dilithium, or….